# Error in NamedStoredProcedureQuery in Spring JPA - "Found named stored procedure parameter associated with positional parameters"

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to call a Stored Procedure written in Postgresql using the NamedStoredProcedureQuery provided by Spring JPA. Following are code snippets.

**EntityMovement.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity_movement")
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
    @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "near_by_entities", 
                               procedureName = "near_by_entities",
                               parameters = {
                                     @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "location", type = String.class),
                                     @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "radius", type = Double.class),
                                     @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR, type = void.class)
                               })
})
public class EntityMovement implements Serializable{

//Fields

//Getters and Setters

}
```

**EntityMovementRepository**

```
@Repository
public interface EntityMovementRepository extends JpaRepository<EntityMovement, Entity>{
    @Procedure(name = "near_by_entities")
    public List<EntityMovement> nearByEntities(@Param("location")String location,@Param("radius")double radius);

}
```

**Calling**

```
List<EntityMovement> entityMovements= entityMovementRepository.nearByEntities(location, radius);
```

**`Stored Procedure`**

*Query is simplified*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.near_by_entities(
location character varying,
radius double precision)
RETURNS refcursor
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
DECLARE ref refcursor;
BEGIN
OPEN ref FOR SELECT * FROM public.entity_movement;
RETURN ref;
END
$BODY$;
```

**Stack Trace**

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Found named stored procedure parameter associated with positional parameters; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Found named stored procedure parameter associated with positional parameters
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:381) ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:246) ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:488) ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) ~[spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147) ~[spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy210.nearByEntities(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.onwards.LocationEngine.business.EntityMovementBusinessImpl.findNearByEntities(EntityMovementBusinessImpl.java:38) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.onwards.LocationEngine.business.EntityMovementBusinessImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$99567b2c.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at com.onwards.LocationEngine.business.EntityMovementBusinessImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b7870dee.findNearByEntities(<generated>) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at com.onwards.LocationEngine.controller.EntityMovementController.findNearByEntities(EntityMovementController.java:37) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[servlet-api.jar:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:115) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [catalina.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.23]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_144]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.23]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
```

I am new to Spring JPA and it's annotations. The name of the parameter is clearly mentioned in the `@StoredProcedureParameter` and the same is being used with the `@param` in repository function. This seems like a very straight forward error message as it says that I am using named parameters instead of positional parameters and I am missing something very obvious. But I am not able to find any solution in any of the forums.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

**EDIT - Adding Table Structure**

`CREATE TABLE public.entity_movement
(
  entity bigint NOT NULL,
  location geography NOT NULL,
  movement_time timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_entity PRIMARY KEY (entity),
  CONSTRAINT fk2sd7ux7x1atbbpdl4y0lwc9la FOREIGN KEY (entity)
      REFERENCES public.entity (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_entity FOREIGN KEY (entity)
      REFERENCES public.entity (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
)`

Comment: Have you tried reordering the attribute names on defining the procedure parameters? In all examples that I've found they go "name, mode, type". Also in some versions there was a bug in relation with cursors: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33638491/2553194 It seems that somehow ParameterStrategy is been set to POSITIONAL instead of NAMED. Hope someone can help you.

Comment: have you solved your problem? In that case, please post the solution so we all can learn :-)

Comment: @RubioRic I tried all kinds of permutations and combinations for a whole day, but nothing was happening. While I was trying, the error message kept on changing between "You are using named parameters for positional parameters" to "The return type was JDBC.Types.1111 but JDBC.Types.2012 was registered". It was for an urgent prototype, so I had to resort to use JDBC(In a spring-boot, hibernate project:() to finish it. So I didn't find any solution yet. I just did a work around

Answer (score 9):

The root of the problem is that you are mixing named and positional parameters. 
The [JPA 2.1 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html) in section **3.10.17.1 Named Stored Procedure Queries** states that this usage leads to undefined behavior:

> If parameter names are used, the parameter name is used to bind the parameter value and to extract the output value (if the parameter is INOUT or OUT parameter). If parameter names are not specified, it is assumed that positional parameters are used. The mixing of named and positional parameters is undefined.

This can also be the reason why Hibernate - when determining the parameter strategy - checks only the first stored procedure parameter in [`ParameterDefinition#L156`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/annotations/NamedProcedureCallDefinition.java#L156).

The "Found named stored procedure parameter associated with positional parameters" error message is a bit misleading because in [`ProcedureCallImpl#L423`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/procedure/internal/ProcedureCallImpl.java#L243) the same error message is used when the parameter strategy is named but the parameter is positional and the other way around. The error message in your case should be this: "Found positional stored procedure parameter associated with named parameters" (since in your case the strategy was defined as named but your last `REF_CURSOR` parameter is positional).

To fix this we can add a name to the `REF_CURSOR` parameter:

```java
@StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR, name = "out", type = void.class)
```

But unfortunately this will lead to another (misleading) error message:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: PostgreSQL supports only one REF_CURSOR parameter, but multiple were registered
```

Despite having registered only one `REF_CURSOR` parameter we get an error message about having registered more than one. The exception is thrown by [`PostgresCallableStatementSupport#L66`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/procedure/internal/PostgresCallableStatementSupport.java#L66) and in fact its [`renderCallableStatement()`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/procedure/internal/PostgresCallableStatementSupport.java#L31) method contains several useful information about the requirements when there is a `REF_CURSOR` parameter defined:

- It should be the first parameter
- The parameter strategy has to be positional

And also in a comment in [`renderCallableStatement()`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/procedure/internal/PostgresCallableStatementSupport.java#L31) method it is explicitly stated that mixing named and positional parameters is not allowed.

So we should remove the provided names:

```
@StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR, type = void.class),
@StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class),
@StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = Double.class)
```

Since currently Spring Data does not support the overriding of positional parameter mapping (only [named parameter mapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.9.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.stored-procedures)) and our first parameter is a `REF_CURSOR` we get the following error message when Spring Data tries to map `REF_CURSOR` to the first method parameter defined in the repository interface:

```java
InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [location] did not match expected type [void (n/a)]
```

So `@Procedure` can no longer be used but as a workaround we can create and implement a separate `EntityMovementRepositoryWithProcedure` interface and do the mapping manually:

```java
public interface EntityMovementRepositoryWithProcedure {
    List<EntityMovement> nearByEntities(String location, double radius);
}

@Repository
public interface EntityMovementRepository extends JpaRepository<EntityMovement, Integer>, EntityMovementRepositoryWithProcedure { }

public class EntityMovementRepositoryImpl implements EntityMovementRepositoryWithProcedure {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<EntityMovement> nearByEntities(String location, double radius) {
        StoredProcedureQuery nearByEntities em.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("near_by_entities");
        nearByEntities.setParameter(2, location);
        nearByEntities.setParameter(3, radius);
        return nearByEntities.getResultList();
    }
}
```

Also [autocommit has to be disabled when using PostgreSQL `REF_CURSOR`](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/401FD247.8080605%40xythos.com) otherwise the following exception will be thrown when calling the stored procedure:

```java
PSQLException: ERROR: cursor "<unnamed portal 1>" does not exist
```

A fully working example is available here: https://github.com/sandor-balazs/example/tree/master/spring-data-postgresql-refcursor.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation of why the error is coming. However, I had already tried the workaround you suggested at the end of your answer while I was stuck with the issue. The error was `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A CallableStatement function was executed and the out parameter 1 was of type java.sql.Types=1111 however type java.sql.Types=2012 was registered.` But again  I tried your suggestion just now to make sure I didn't miss any possible solution. I had to resort to JDBC to make this work.

Comment: @PriyaAnil Could you please update your question with more details about the table structure that you are using? I tried to reproduce your error but I don't get `PSQLException` related to wrong registered types. I have also updated my answer with a link to a fully working example.

Comment: @SandorBalazs nice explaination

Comment: @SandorBalazs I have added the Table structure to question. I guess the culprit is the 'Geography' type used  by location field. It is a  postgis datatype. I can see you  have used String.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add a name to the out parameter:

```
@StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR, name = "out", type = void.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the spring-data jpa example for jpa2.1 for using Stored procedure

[spring-data-examples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/jpa21)

There represents two different interpretation of the call to the repository method one which explicitly maps with annotation metadata and other derives procedure metadata from the repository.

> Calling UserRepository.plus1BackedByOtherNamedStoredProcedure(…) will execute the stored procedure plus1inout using the meta-data declared on the User domain class.
>
> UserRepository.plus1inout(…) will derive stored procedure metadata from the repository and default to positional parameter binding and expect a single output parameter of the backing stored procedure.

In here, this might be the case the call to nearByEntities is getting resolved by deriving from repo and that is positional?

To get a try we can update the name inside annotation

```
 @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "near_by_entities",
```

To

```
 @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "EntityMovement.nearByEntities",
```

Along with

```
@Procedure(name = "near_by_entities")
public List<EntityMovement> nearByEntities(@Param("location")String location,@Param("radius")double radius);
```

To

```
@Procedure(name = "EntityMovement.nearByEntities")
public List<EntityMovement> nearByEntitiesNamed(@Param("location")String location,@Param("radius")double radius);
```

Calling would be

```
List<EntityMovement> entityMovements= entityMovementRepository.nearByEntitiesNamed(location, radius);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try it out soon to clarify whether it works or not.

Comment: I tried your code snippet, and I am getting following Error,
`Type cannot be null
 at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.setHibernateType(AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl.java:178) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]`

And I see this warning also at top

`o.h.p.internal.ProcedureCallImpl         : HHH000456: Named parameters are used for a callable statement, but database metadata indicates named parameters are not supported.`

Comment: @PriyaAnil regarding the warning there is an explanation on the hibernate community the issues are with the sql driver in use and the warning can be ignored https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1043165

Comment: @PriyaAnil Can you do a favor, please? Activate the trace logging for the hibernate and get the logs for the workflow involved. The kind of query it is trying to build and bind the parameter.

Comment: Please find the logs in the following link,

https://pastebin.com/w8tYTkvz

No equivalent SQL queries are getting generated.

Comment: @PriyaAnil Thanks, Going through the stack trace it is somewhat trickier as the Source code of AbstractParameterRegistrationImpl get onto this kind of issue when corresponding hibernateType is not able to resolve. But, for the exact pin-point you might need to turn on the debug to dive-in that class. Meanwhile, can you switch the order of the parameters attribute value inside @NamedStoredProcedureQuery;  and make REF_CURSOR as the first parameter to be declared instead of last

Comment: The error remains the same as the one I posted in paste bin. Is this a problem caused by hibernate's implementation of function calls for PostgreSQL? I have even cross checked with a tutorial doing the same thing with PostgreSQL. I have written the same code 
https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/call-stored-procedures-jpa/

Answer (score 0):

In the parameters = {} which you have provided, for couple of them you have explicitly provided 'name', whereas for the third one you haven't.

Probably it is not able to understand whether the parameters should be considered on the basis of 'names' or position.

Either provide the name for all three, or none of them. (In your case please give a try by removing the 'name' from both the paramters.)